# How do I access two arrays with different sizes at the same time?

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I have beeen looking at six arrays that I have, one of them is smaller than than the others. I want to print the in this form:

1. El sustantivo 
   I.  Elige el uso correcto del sustantivo entrada.
   A.  Uno vez entrada al parque no se resistió. 
   B.  La entrada al parque, no la resistió.
   C.  Entrada la noche, el niño comenzó a llorar.
   D.  Con cada golpe, entrada me encuentro.

II. Escoge la forma correcta en femenino de tigre 
A.  La tigresa tiene buenas garras.
B.  La trigresa tiene buenas garras.
C.  La triga tiene buenas garras.
D.  La tigera tiene buenas garras.

III.    Cambiar al plural: El árbol de bambú es la planta que crece más rápido en todo el planeta. 
A.  Los arboles bambúses son las plantas que crecen más rápido en todo el planeta.
B.  Las bambús son las plantas que crecen más rápido en todo el planeta.
C.  Los arboles de bambú son las plantas que crecen más rápido en todo el planeta.
D.  Los arbols de bambúes son las plantas que crecen más rápido en todo el planeta.

I have this, but no good result.

public class FileArrays {

```
private static String[] keys = new String[60];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // System.out.println("Al final la vida sigue igual");
    System.out.println();

    //String fileName = "filearrays.txt";

    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileName);

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f;

        String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            /*
             * System.out.print("\""); System.out.print(line);
             * System.out.print("\",");
             */
            // System.out.println();
            lineNumber++;

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < pregs.length; i++) {

        /*
         * System.out.print("\""); System.out.print(keys[i]);
         * System.out.print("\",");
         */

    }


        temas();
        pregunta();


}

private static void temas() {
    for(int i = 0; i < temas.length; i++){
    System.out.println(temas[i]);
    }





}

private static void pregunta() {

    for (int i = 0; i < pregs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\t" + pregs[i]);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + resp1[i]);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + resp2[i]);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + resp3[i]);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + resp4[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your requirement.
Are the array elements somehow connected to each other other than by the array index?

By which criteria do you start the sections marked with the roman numbers?

**[edit]**
possible solution:

```
class Topic{
    private final String topic;
    private finaltopicName Collection<Question> questions;
    Topic(String topic, Collection<Question> ... questions){
        this.topic=topic;
        this.questions=Arrays.asList(questions);
    }
}

class Question{
    private final String question;
    private final Collection<String> answers;
    Question(String question, Collection<String>... answers){
        this.question=question;
        this.answers=Arrays.asList(answers);
}
```

Comment: The roman numerals are questions which should come from the "pregs" array. The capitals are the answers for each questions. There are four answers one is correct. The temas array is topic, it has to have three questions for each topic. So what I want is to get the first topic, ask three questions for that topic, and go to the next topic, but I want to use the next index of the other arrays.

Comment: Topic one
      Question 1

Comment: Still don't get it. 
There  are topics and question, but there are more than 2 arrays.
how does that fit together?

Comment: The others are four answers to the same question. One is the correct one.

Comment: is there a possibility to change your design? I'd suggest that you create custom Objects `Topic` and `Question`. the `Topic` objects hold a list of `Question` objects and they in turn contain a list of answers.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, why not? I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer. What I wanted to do was to go though an array that involved another array smaller in size. So what I did was to get the bigger array, and compare if the index pass some indexes, if that happened then the smaller array was going to increase one so that I do not get arrayoutofbound exception.

Here is my solution for your who voted me down, but you did not know the answer losers.

```
private static void calendar() {
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayBigger.length; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i == 0){
    System.out.println(smallerArray[p]);
    p = p + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("\t" + pregs[i]);
    System.out.println("\t\t" +resp1[i]);
    System.out.println("\t\t" + resp2[i]);
    System.out.println("\t\t" + resp3[i]);
    System.out.println("\t\t" + resp4[i]);  

}
}
```